# Merging/converting VirtualFileDataObject and System.Windows.Forms.DataObject

Tags: .net-4.6

I'm trying to pass files from a database during a drag & drop operation, with multiple formats:

- if the drag occurs within the same process, just pass the file ID; the destination control will know how to handle it
- if the drag occurs to a different app, pass a stream to download the file upon drop

The former is simple enough with `DataObject`, and the latter can be accomplished using `VirtualFileDataObject`. However, `VirtualFileDataObject` doesn't have APIs as convenient as `DataObject`s, and I'm unsure how to pass the same information to it (or whether it's even possible at all).

Specifically, I do the former as follows:

```
[Serializable]
private class FileDragDropInfo
{
    public int FileID { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
private class FileDragDropInfoArray
{
    public FileDragDropInfo[] Files { get; set; }
}

[..]

var data = new DataObject();
data.SetData(new FileDragDropInfoArray { .Files = items.ToArray() });
```

And the latter as follows:

```
var vData = new VirtualFileDataObject.VirtualFileDataObject();
vData.SetData(items.Select(i => new VirtualFileDataObject.VirtualFileDataObject.FileDescriptor
{
    Name = i.FileName,
    StreamContents = (s) => { /* download the stream here */ }
}));
```

These both work individually.

However, `VirtualFileDataObject` unfortunately lacks methods like `GetData()` to add that format back to the original `DataObject`. Conversely, `VirtualFileDataObject` also (unlike `DataObject`) doesn't have an overload that performs the conversion.

It does, however, have this overload:

```
public void SetData(short dataFormat, IEnumerable<byte> data);
```

I'm guessing the first parameter is identical with the `Id` property in System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Format, so the first part of this might work:

```
foreach (var format in data.GetFormats().Select(f => System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.GetFormat(f))
{
    vData.SetData(format.Id, /* how do I pass the data? */);
}
```

However, having skimmed the source code of System.Windows.Forms.DataObject, I'm at a loss where and how its conversion/serialization of passed data takes place such that I can pass it as the second parameter as a `byte[]`. Related code like `SaveDataToHandle()` and the entire `DataStore` class are also private, so I wouldn't be able to call them directly (barring reflection).

I haven't actually *tried* if all I need to do is pass such a handle. Am I on the right track there?

Will passing additional formats to `VirtualFileDataObject` work *at all*, or are the two fundamentally incompatible? (Or will I have to extend `VirtualFileDataObject` to support this?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, at least for `DataFormats.Serializable`, and implemented it as an extension method `ImportDataObject` for now:

```
public static class VirtualFileDataObjectExtensions
{
    public static void ImportDataObject(this ref VirtualFileDataObject.VirtualFileDataObject virtualFileDataObject, DataObject dataObject)
    {
        if (virtualFileDataObject == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(virtualFileDataObject));
        if (dataObject == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataObject));

        foreach (var format in dataObject.GetFormats())
        {
            short formatIDShort = _GetShortFormatID(format);

            var data = dataObject.GetData(format);

            // we only support Serializable for now
            if (format.Equals(DataFormats.Serializable) || data is ISerializable || data?.GetType().IsSerializable)
                virtualFileDataObject.SetData(formatIDShort, _SerializeDataObject(data));
        }
    }

    private static short _GetShortFormatID(string format)
    {
        // unfortunately, .NET uses an int, but ushort would be correct
        ushort formatID = System.Convert.ToUInt16(DataFormats.GetFormat(format).Id & 0xFFFF);
        short formatIDShort;

        // and VirtualFileDataProvider takes a short instead of a ushort
        unchecked { formatIDShort = (short)formatID; }

        return formatIDShort;
    }

    private readonly static byte[] _serializedObjectID = new Guid(0xFD9EA796, 0x3B13, 0x4370, 0xA6, 0x79, 0x56, 0x10, 0x6B, 0xB2, 0x88, 0xFB).ToByteArray();
    private static byte[] _SerializeDataObject(object data)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(ms))
            {
                binaryWriter.Write(_serializedObjectID);

                var formatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(ms, data);
            }

            ms.FlushAsync();

            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

This code could probably take some clean-up, but it works great for me.